# Store cucumber reports into different working directory

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

The working directory where I run tests are read only and so my cucumber runner fails to create the report directory.

So, is there any way to specify different directory to **plugin** option?

```
@CucumberOptions(
         features = "resources/features",
         glue = "stepdef",
         plugin = {"pretty", "json:<custom_path>"} ,
         tags = {"@test1"}
  )
```

Here, by 'custom_path' I mean something outside of my package directory where I will have read access.

Answer (score 1):

You can change reports directory. Here is an example from [here](https://testingneeds.wordpress.com/2015/09/15/junit-runner-with-cucumberoptions/):

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty" ,"html:Folder_Name" ,
                           "json:Folder_Name/cucumber.json" ,
                           "junit:Folder_Name/cucumber.xml"})
```

Comment: But this will also try to create the folder under same parent directory only. My concern is that my package's directory `user.dir` will not have write access. So want to give some other drive's path. Will it accept the absolute path?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. Why don't you try it out and let us know?

Comment: Oh no, I didn't think about trying with an absolute path before  just tried with my Mac and it actually works. Will try the same at my linux remote and see where I actually have permission issue.